# При добавлении в Room кидает ошибку

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rxandroid, android-room

хочу получить данные с помощью retrofit и сохранить в Room.

Но возникает ошибка

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Disposable! but Article was expected
```

Как можно исправить ошибку?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var articles: Observable<ArrayList<Article>>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val apiService = ApiService.create()

        val articles = apiService.getTopHeadlines("techcrunch", APIUrl.newsApi)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            result -> result.articles
                        },
                        {
                            throwable: Throwable? -> Log.d("Ошибка",throwable.toString())
                        }
                )

        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
        val articleDao = db.articleDao()
        articleDao.insert(articles)
    }
}
```

AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [(Article::class)], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun articleDao(): IArticleDao

    companion object {
        private var sInstance: AppDatabase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = Room
                        .databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "example")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
            }
            return sInstance!!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод subscribe() возвращает disposable, который может быть использован для отмены подписки. Данные, котрые нужно добавить в базу, приходят подписчику, который Вы передаете в subscribe. Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
val disposable = apiService.getTopHeadlines("techcrunch", APIUrl.newsApi)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
                {
                    result -> articleDao.insert(result.articles)
                },
                {
                    throwable: Throwable? -> Log.d("Ошибка",throwable.toString())
                }
        )
```

observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) - здесь тоже не нужен, т.к при попытке записи в базу в главном потоке, Room выбросит ошибку.

Comment: Автор UI хочет обновлять, поэтому на mainThread подписался.

Comment: Вопрос - "При добавлении в Room кидает ошибку", про UI ничего не сказано.

Answer (score 1):

Я не использую `Rx`, но насколько помню, метод `subscribe()` ничего не возвращает. `Ничего` в понятиях `Kotlin` это `kotlin.Unit`, который вы пытаетесь запихнуть в `Room`, вот он и ругается. Это во-первых.

Во-вторых, код в принципе неверен для асинхронных операций. Результат надо сохранять в момент его появления, а не сразу после подписки на него.

Comment: Я конечно не эксперт, но в данном участке кода .subscribe({ result ->

                    renderComponent(result.articles)

                }, {
                    throwable: Throwable? ->Log.d("Ошибка", throwable.toString())

                }
                ) у меня возвращается ответ от сервера и я передаю его в функцию в котором рендерится компонент (аналог layout)

Comment: Ну а так вы правы, насчет Unit, ошибка была именно в этом

Comment: Насчет 2 аргумента. Как по вашему мнению стоит сделать тогда? (желательно код)

Comment: Напишите в этой лямбде не только вызов метода для ренденига, но и для записи в Room. Только запись в Room надо отдельным потоком делать, подписка у вас на mainThread.